# Is Android application signature per developer, per package or per package version?

Tags: java, android, signing

The documentation of Android application [Signature](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/Signature.html), as returned by in [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#signatures) (by PackageManager), seems somewhat unclear. It may reflect

- The developer signature that have been used to sign the app. Then it would be one signature for all apps signed by the same key.
- A signature for this package name. Then it would be one signature for all versions of the app that has this package name.
- If apk files have different contents, they have different signatures.

Which one is true?

Answer (score 0):

A signature is for a package (app). see the Signature documentation:

> Opaque, immutable representation of a signature ***associated with an application package***.

Answer (score 0):

It's number 1 on your list - whatever key the developer used to sign the app with.

You can see the contents of the signature for each app using [App Detective](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zmarties.detective). [Full disclosure - I wrote that app]